Linux + how to change the TYPE to be correctly
is it possible to re-configure the TYPE from raid1 to part as should be
example:
lsblk -l
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    0  180G  0 disk
sda1           8:1    0    1G  0 raid1 /boot
sda2           8:2    0  179G  0 raid1
sdb            8:16   0   10G  0 disk
vg-lVM_root 253:0    0   50G  0 lvm  /
vg-lVM_swap 253:1    0  7.7G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
vg-lVM_var  253:2    0  100G  0 lvm  /var

example of what we need:
lsblk -l
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    0  180G  0 disk
sda1           8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
sda2           8:2    0  179G  0 part
sdb            8:16   0   10G  0 disk
vg-lVM_root 253:0    0   50G  0 lvm  /
vg-lVM_swap 253:1    0  7.7G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
vg-lVM_var  253:2    0  100G  0 lvm  /var

Note - The server is RHEL version 7.6
The reason for change is because most of our servers are with part and few of them are with raid1 and we want to alignment the servers with raid1 to be exactly as the servers that appears with part
so what are the steps that should be done in order to change the Type from raid1 to part ?
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities :
unused devices: <none>

fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 193.3 GB, 193273528320 bytes, 377487360 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00005995

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200   377487359   187694080   8e  Linux LVM


Is this a complete lsblk? Show also cat /proc/mdstat and fdisk -l /dev/sda.

Strange. Arrays aren't started and aren't used. Probably, you just have stray RAID metadata there, which lsblk sees.  mdadm --examine /dev/sda1 then? If it's able to interpret the superblock mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda1 should suffice to remove it, not touching the actual data.

Let me add, that's safe to do only if you have v0.9 or v1.0 superblock. Don't do this it it's v1.1 or v1.2 superblock; but, if that's the case, you wouldn't be able to access the data on the partition that easily without starting the array like you did, so it is very unlikely.
